# Find the number of real solutions of the equation $3x+tanx =\frac{5\pi}{2}$ in ......

Tags: trigonometry

Problem : 
Find the number of real solutions of the equation $3x+tanx =\frac{5\pi}{2}$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$

My approach :

Shall I put the value in the given interval and match, please suggest a proper way out of such problem, will be of great help, thanks.

Comment: One quick way of finding the number of solutions is by plotting $tanx$ and $\frac{5\pi}{2}-3x$, counting their intersection points which is equal to 2.

Comment: Newton-Raphson algorithm could be used to find a root of $3x +\tan x - \frac{5 \pi}{2}$. You would have to make sure that your initial starting point for the first iteration is in the desired region. With only some iterations you will be very close to the root already. If you notice that you are finding a root outside your desired region, try with a different initial value.

Answer (score 1):

Draw graph of $y=\tan x$ and $\displaystyle y = \frac{5\pi}{2}-3x$ in coordinate axis in $0\leq x\leq \pi$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \tan(x)+3x$ and $k=\dfrac{5\pi}{2}$. We see that $f$ is **strictly** increasing, and $f(0) = 0$

Also, for $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}), f >0$ . So one root of $f(x)-k$ lies in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Also, notice that $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi^{+}}{2}}f(x) = -\infty$, and $f(\pi) = 3\pi$. So one more root lies in $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$

Hence a total of $2$ roots.